# Insert line break/special character in string in file

Tags: batch, script

I have USER.TXT file.
File contain text:

```
123,234,987,877,356
```

I looking for script to modify text in the same file to:

```
123
234
987
877
356
```

Please, help me out for editing a text file without redirecting the output to a new file.

So Far I Have:

```
@echo off 
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=%,"
set "replace=%%"

set "textFile=USERS.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Thank you appreciate all help!!!

Comment: Did not work. Here is the Output I'm getting:

Comment: See [Accepting an Answer](https://i.imgur.com/OZho1tT.png) to ensure you understand how that works for the solution you find for any answers that help you resolve your problem by simply checking the little gray check box to the upper left side of the answer that resolves your problem assuming one does and turn it green to show it's the answer you accepted since that's how that is supposed to work; you ask a question, you get answers, and if you get an answer that works for your needs, you simply accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Batch Script to Replace Comma with `CRLF`

If this is batch enough for you, give it a shot as it seems to be simple and just works . . .

> **The below batch script will essentially:**
>
> - Use [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html) and [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html) for the string to search (`,`)
>     and replace (`CRLF`)
> - Then it will use [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html) to put the newly
>     replaced string back into the file accordingly

**Note:** *The `set textFile=` value should be either the full explicit path to the text file you'll change commas to `CRLF` (e.g. `C\Folder\Path\USERS.txt`), or else if this script is in the exact same folder as that file, the value of the `set textFile=` should be prefixed with `%~dp0` (e.g. `%~dp0USERS.txt`)*

```
@echo on

set search=,
set textFile=C:\Folder\Path\USERS.txt
::set textFile=%~dp0USERS.txt

:PowerShell
SET PSScript=%temp%\~tmpStrRplc.ps1
ECHO (Get-Content "%textFile%").replace("%search%", "`r`n") ^| Set-Content "%textFile%">"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"
EXIT
```

---

**Original File Content**

```
123,234,987,877,356
```

**Result File Content**

```
123
234
987
877
356
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Get-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/get-content.html)
- [Replace](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)
- [Set-Content](https://ss64.com/ps/set-content.html)

Comment: Did not work . Getting error on output:Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Users.txt' because it does not exist

Comment: @GeorgeDudnikov I just edited my answer with a correction to resolve that. I used the full explicit path in my testing but I added a **Note** section with two solutions that should work for you depending on your setup.

Comment: Thank you very Much!! Excellent Resolution!!!. you are the Best!

Comment: @GeorgeDudnikov See [Accepting an Answer](https://i.imgur.com/OZho1tT.png) to ensure you understand how that works for the solution you find for any answers that help you resolve your problem by simply checking the little gray check box to the upper left side of the answer that resolves your problem assuming one does and turn it green to show it's the answer you accepted since that's how that is supposed to work; you ask a question, you get answers, and if you get an answer that works for your needs, you simply accept that answer.